# simple GPS server with node.js?

Tags: linux, gps, node.js

I have to create a simple service on linux VPS (IP: 1.2.3.4). So whatever text/data will be sent to that linux server 1.2.3.4:6345 it will post that text/data to a website.

Some thing like

```
Server 1.2.3.4 listening at port: 6345  
Received text: 'lng: 12.00, lat: 14.00, DeviceId: E8f4kakh'
/*I will convert text to proper query params*/
Post data to www.mywebsite.com/data
```

I have no idea about linux programming. Can I do this using node.js? or any other simple language?

Comment: *"I have no idea about linux programming"* - instead of telling us what you don't know, tell us what you **do** know so that we know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you're talking about a tcp server:

```
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var mywebsite = http.createClient(80, 'www.mywebsite.com');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write("GPS relay server\r\n");
  socket.on("data", function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      var request = google.request('POST', '/data',
        {'host': 'www.mywebsite.com'});
      request.end(convertTextToProperQueryParams(data));
      request.on('response', function (response) {
        socket.write('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
      });
  });
});

server.listen(6345);

console.log('server listening on port 6345');

function convertTextToProperQueryParams(data) {
    return ProperQueryParams;
};
```